# Determining resistor values for common source amplifier

Tags: mosfet, amplifier

I want to design a Common Source Amplifier. I will be using an lnd_150 [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/LND150-LND250-N-Channel-Depletion-Mode-DMOS-FETs-Data-Sheet-20005454A.pdf).

I need to get the most gain out of the mosfet, as it will be used with a potentiometer before to adjust the gain.

The lnd has ID.min=1mA ID.max=3mA, I will set it to 2mA (I follow this formula [Idq= (Idmin + Id max)/2]). Then I understood this :

Rd=320V/2mA=160K

I have read (Allow 1/3VCC across Rd, Vds and R2):

VDD=320V/3=106.7V

Since I use 2mA : Rd=106.7V/2mA=53.4K

R1=160K*66%=106K
R2=160K*33%=54K

Then I am lost because now it seem I have to make Rs 160k, to have amplification.
On another link [here](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/amplifier/mosfet-amplifier.html) I have read you need to determine Vd and Vs before Rd and Rs. Now I am really lost, I someone could explain me step by step how to do it, I will be grateful. Thank you.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNWcbs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Are you aware that your MOSFET is a Depletion type of a MOSFET? Do you know what that means?

Comment: Does it mean I don't need the bias resistors ? Thank you.

Comment: What will be load of this amplifier?

Comment: It will be 600ohm and also 47k, I need line level +4dbu. I will use a potentiometer before the circuit to adjust the gain.

Comment: But why 320V?? And yes, if you short the gate to the GND your D-MOS still will be ON. And the drain current will flow. And this current will be between 1mA...3mA (1.8mA average)

Comment: This makes a lousy linear amplifier because *The LND150 and LND250 are high-voltage N-channel
Depletion-mode (normally-on) transistors utilizing
lateral DMOS technology. The gate is ESD protected.
The LND150/LND250 are ideal for high-voltage applications, such as normally-on switches, precision
constant-current sources, voltage-ramp generation
and amplification."*  **Unless you use  negative feedback**  So What are your design specs??

Comment: Lnd It's just what I have left from another project, and 320V it's the supply of my microphone preamp I built Years ago. I am reusing the power supply. But I am interested in the theory behind choosing the value, because I may be buying another mosfet later. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I consider Rs is connected to GND.

The gain will be equal to:

`-gm*(Rd//R5//Rload)`

note: double slash means 'in parallel'.

Where `gm = 2*Id/(Vgs-Vtn(***))`

(***) - Mosfet parameter, known as threshold voltage.

And `Id = 1/2 * Kn(mosfet parameter) * (Vgs-Vtn)^2`

For AC small signal, source of the nMos will be at ground level, but for DC, you have to consider the voltage difference between gate and source, and the voltage on the drain should satisfy:

`Vds > Vgs - Vtn`

Combine all these requirements and formulas and try to arrange DC values Vg, Vd, Vs and Id so that you achieve your desired gain.

Comment: Thank you I think I get it now. Will I have less noise if I don't use the voltage divider bias resistors for the gate ? since I use a depletion device ON.

Comment: @fredericoacardi I don't have any info about it